# Condition based on level of detail of data (decimal system)

Tags: tableau-api

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3oLNt.png)My data has **10 categories** each with up to **2-5 levels**.
Each category string is 1.0, 2.0, etc up to 10.
Level 1 is a subset of greater detail, so 1.1, 2.1.
Level 2 is (two decimal places) 1.1.1. 1.1.2, etc.
I produced a **circle chart** for each category.
I need the circle to be **darker** based on whether it has greater detail so the user knows to click it.
All categories have at lease 1 level.
Some have up to 5 (1.1.1.1.1.1) but some have only 2 or 3.
The idea is to produce a **visual queue** to user when to click the circle for greater detail or not.
The reference numbers (decimal system) are formatted as [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Yvive.png)strings`.

Comment: can you share your tableau screen shot or file.

Comment: Ashutosh, I embedded an image which is the model for what I am developing.  The decimal numbers are currently formatted as string (txt),  10 categories which have at least one level 1.1, etc.  Not all have a second, some have a third and few have a fifth level.  I am creating circle chart based on y=level of effort and x= max opportunity (so each level has $$ and LOE associated).  I want circle to indicate there is a another level - as user clicks, it opens up another view of the detail.